# Eliminar item de localstorage despues de un dia

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, local-storage

Hola es la primera vez que uso esto y quisiera eliminar un value true de mi key de localstorage despues de un dia para hacer que la alerta que cree aparezca solo una vez por dia. Trate con todo pero no puedo hacer eso ni con cookies de jquery pude. Soy novato en esto.

```
          $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.overlay_popup').delay(1000).queue(function() {
      $('.overlay_popup').addClass('popup-open')
      });
      });

      $.fn.popupClose = function() {
      $(".overlay_popup").removeClass("popup-open");
      return this;
      };

      $(document).ready(function() {
          setInterval(() => {
          if(!$('.overlay_popup').hasClass('popup-open')){
              $('.overlay_popup').addClass('popup-open');
          }
      },24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
      
      })
      ;



      $PopUp = $('.signup');

        var hide = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('hide'));

        if (hide) {
            $PopUp.hide();
        } else {
            // initialize value in case it hasn't been set already
            localStorage.setItem('hide', false);
        }

        $('.close_btn').click(function() {
            $('.signup' ).hide();
            // toggle the boolean by negating its value
            var hide = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('hide'));
            localStorage.setItem('hide', !hide);
        });
```

Al reiniciar la pagina la alerta ya no sale pero quiero que vuelva a salir despues de 24 horas.

Comment: Junto al `setItem` podrías tambien guardar el Date actual, en el `getItem` comparas la fecha actual con la guardada, si es menor haces el `.hide()` si es mayor, un nuevo `setItem` con una nueva fecha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Un día son 24 horas, que equivalen a 86400 segundos.
Se puede poner `timestamp` como valor de un `localStorage`,
de cual se puede comparar con el actual `timestamp`.
Si es mayor de 86400, se puede mostrar de nuevo el anuncio.

Le he creado un [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3d6s9fba/), la primera vez que lo visite, debería enseñarle el anuncio. Si recarga la página, ya no tiene que ser visible hasta dentro de un día (24 horas).

Minimo HTML:

```
<div class="signup">
Anuncio
</div>
```

La parte Javascript:

```
const $Popup = document.querySelector('.signup');

if (localStorage.getItem("mi_super_anuncio") !== null) {
  if((Math.round(new Date().getTime()/1000) - Number(localStorage.getItem("mi_super_anuncio"))) > 86400 ) {
  // tenemos que mostrar de nuevo el anuncio
     $Popup.classList.add('muestra_anuncio');
    localStorage.setItem("mi_super_anuncio", Math.round(new Date().getTime()/1000));
  }
} else {
    localStorage.setItem("mi_super_anuncio", Math.round(new Date().getTime()/1000));
  $Popup.classList.add('muestra_anuncio');
}
```

CSS, que define si tiene mostrar el anuncio:

```
.signup {
  color: #000;
  display: none;
}

.muestra_anuncio {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: me solucionaste el problema muchas gracias, crees que el localstorage se pueda disparar una vez que presione la X del anuncio? ya que cuando recargo la pagina sin apretar la X el anuncio no sale y la idea es que no salga despues de apretar la X

Comment: Claro, tienes que usar ```localStorage.setItem``` en este ```event```.

Comment: como lo implementarias? en cual evento dices?

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/496368/disparar-localstorage-despues-de-un-click aca formule la pregunta por si me puedes ayudar y entender mejor a si ves todo mi html

Answer (score 0):

[localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), por definición, no tiene fecha de expiración. Para lograr esto, podrías usar funciones personalizadas para guardar/buscar elementos en el localStorage.

En la función para guardar, puedes incluir una hora de expiración en el objeto. Luego, a la hora de buscar, puedes verificar que la hora actual sea menor a la hora de expiración del objeto, y si no lo es, eliminarlo.

Ejemplo:

```js
function guardarConExpiracion(key, value) {
    const data = { 'data': value, 'fecha': new Date() };
    localStorage.setItem(key, data)
}

function buscarConExpiracion(key) {
   const data = localStorage.getItem(key);
   const fecha = new Date();

   if (fecha - data.fecha > (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)) { // un dia en ms
     localStorage.removeItem(key);
     return null;
   } else {
    return data.data
   }
}
```

================

Edito para responder cómo implementar:

```js
        var hide = buscarConExiración('hide');

        if (hide) {
            $PopUp.hide();
        } else {
            // initialize value in case it hasn't been set already
            guardarConExpiracon('hide', false);
        }

        $('.close_btn').click(function() {
            $('.signup' ).hide();
            // toggle the boolean by negating its value
            var hide = buscarConExpiracion('hide');
            guardarConExpiracion('hide', !hide);
        });
```

Comment: gracias por responder, como pego el codigo y hago que funcione con el mio? en serio mi conocimiento es basico en js y quiero que el booleano del localstorage cambie a false despues de 24 horas para que el anuncio salga denuevo y vuelva a true y a si. gracias

Comment: pues copias las funciones en tu código y las llamas en vez de las llamadas a `localStorage.setItem()` y `localStorage.getItem`...

Comment: podrias copiar el codigo? a si me guio te lo agradeceria un monton, por que a mi me sale error

Comment: const data = { 'data': value, 'fecha': new Date();
    localStorage.setItem(key, data)
}

Comment: en esas  lineas me tira rojo

Comment: falta cerrar el objeto despues de `new Date()` -> }

Comment: si ya solucione esa parte pero la verdad que no estoy pudiendo implementar el codigo

Comment: Las Cookies tienen fecha de expiración, no? se podrían utilizar para eso, creo. El uso es similar a localstorage así que podría ser sustituible.